# IOS GAME KIT observe GKInvite

Tags: swift, gamekit

This question is somewhat related to : [IOS GAME KIT - Where do I find pending invitations? GKInvite or AKA how do I accept programmatically an invitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685965/ios-game-kit-where-do-i-find-pending-invitations-gkinvite-or-aka-how-do-i-acc)

There seems no way to observe for incoming invitations in Game Kit, so I am looking for alternatives. Perhaps one alternative is adding an observer to GKInvite? Is this at all possible, and if so how do I create one?

Basically, what I would like to do is to observe and handle incoming invitations programmatically, now when an invitation is send the receiver will see a message from iOS it self. GameKit is not aware that an invite came until it is declined or accepted.

I am trying :

```
GKInvite().addObserver(GKInvite(), forKeyPath: GKInvite().sender , options: .initial, context: GKPlayer)
```

and

```
GKInvite().observe( \GKInvite.sender , options: .initial){ person, change in
                    print ( "SMTH CHANGED", person, change )
                }
```

The last one gives me a warning : Result of call to 'observe(_:options:changeHandler:)' is unused

But perhaps someone here knows if it is at all possible and if so, how?

GKInvite is an NSObject, and from what I have learned so far, its possible to observer for changes in an NSObject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This

```
func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {}
```

works to receive invites, but you have to make sure to add

```
GKLocalPlayerListener
```

after the class name, eg.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GKLocalPlayerListener{
```

and you also have to make sure to register the player for updates with

```
GKLocalPlayer.local.register(self)
```

after the player is authenticated

Comment: Hi Connor, thank you for your answer. However it is not what I am after. But I see that it is my mistake as my question is not clear. What I would like to do is to observe and handle incoming invitations programmatically, now when an invitation is send the receiver will see a message from iOS it self. GameKit is not aware that an invite came until it is declined or accepted. Hopefully this makes it more clear

Comment: @user1973842 Ok I see what you mean now. As far as I know, this is not possible. I have not seen anything in the documentation that supports this functionality.